# use knockoutjs to load children when a user clicks view details

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of people and each person has a list of pets. 
I would like to get the list of people on page load.
I only want to load a list of one persons pets if the users clicks *view pets*

[image]

here is the jsfiddle   uses coffeescript

http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/rScSL/15/

the getPets seems to be called over and over just when loading

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getPets()">view pets</a>
```

**EDIT**

I have figured it out by adding methods to the Person object directly.
http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/rScSL/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no idea i could add methods to the Person class

I added the getPets Method in Person in order to get my own list of pets

```
Person = (data) ->
    name = ko.observable(data.name)
    lname = ko.observable(data.lname)  
    pets = ko.observableArray(data.pets)  
    getPets = (person) ->  
        data = '{"pets":[
            {"age": "5", "type": "dog"},
            {"age": "4", "type": "cat"}
        ]}'  
        json = $.parseJSON(data).pets 
        mappedItems = $.map(json , (i)->  Pet(i)  )  
        pets(mappedItems) 
    name:name
    lname:lname 
    pets:pets  
    getPets:getPets
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/rScSL/21/

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `click` binding (or `event` binding), you want to bind it against a reference to a function and not the actual invocation of it.

So, you would just want to do:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.getPets">view pets</a>
```

Otherwise, the code is actually getting executed.  You would likely not want to do this unless the function returns the actual function that you want to use.